# In TinyLog what is the platform independent format character for new line in tinylog.properties

Tags: tinylog

In tinylog.properties what do you you specify as the platform independant character for new line ?

Answer (score 0):

In tinylog.properties, you can use Unix like new lines `\n` or Windows like new lines `\r\n`. Both should work platform independently on all common JVMs and Android devices.

However, you cannot change the line separator for log files via tinylog.properties. The default line separator can only be changed for the entire JVM via system properties. You can do it via your command line, e.g. `java -jar MyApp.jar -Dline.separator=$'\n'` on Linux.